# Flask renders css file as empty

Tags: python, css, flask

I've been working on a simple Flask app, and at some point decided to add custom CSS styling alongside Bootstrap. However, for some reason, this CSS file is rendered as empty file. Whether I open it with `http://localhost:5000/static/style.css` or inspect with Firebug, the result is the same. bootstrap.min.css is loaded but style.css is empty, although it's actually not empty.

Templates:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/lib/bootstrap.min.css') }}" > 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" >
```

CSS folder path is `app_root/static/css/style.css` and `app_root/static/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css`

But as I already mentioned, the files are loaded.

Has anyone had any similar issues?

**EDIT:**

At first I thought it was a CSS problem so I did a lot of editing. This is what style.css currently looks like:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: #aaa;
}

p {
    font: Arial;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

What I mean by "the file being empty" is that once it's loaded, it's loaded empty. 
I still don't know why this is happening, but after playing with it for a while, I've noticed that it has something to do with the file name. For example, if I rename **style.css** to **main.css** and load that into html everything works fine.

As you can see, both files are loaded. style.css and bootstrap.min.css

[image]

Bootstraps content:

[image]

style.css content

[image]

After renaming style.css to **main.css**

[image]

Recursive directory structure:

```
project/static/css:
lib/  style.css

project/static/css/lib:
bootstrap-theme.css  bootstrap-theme.min.css  bootstrap.css  bootstrap.min.css
```

**EDIT 2:**

Also, I've managed to recreate this identical problem in a separate test project (in a different virtualenv) with a simple *app.py* module, *static* and *template* folders.

**EDIT 3:**
Test app code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template    

app = Flask(__name__)        

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Folder structure is the same:

```
test/

./test:
app.py
static/
templates/

./test/static:
css/

./test/static/css:
lib/
main.css

./test/static/css/lib:
bootstrap.min.css

./test/templates:
index.html
```

And the app is started with:

```
python app.py
```

Comment: I think you need to give more information or share your code. What is the working URL for bootstrap.min.css? What do the logs say?

Comment: And what do you mean by "style.css is empty, although it's actually not empty". What does it contain then? Paste its contents in your question.

Comment: How do you initialize your flask app? How do you render your templates? Would you mind sharing the second application that produces the same results?

Comment: Of course, added test app code in the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: I was wrong about Flask serving empty CSS. Flask wasn't the problem, browser was. Browser was open for a long time and initially it cached css file as empty (because initially the file was empty).

It appears that simplest solution to this problem  would be to turn off browser caching in any of the developer tools (Firebug in my case). Other solution would be to add HTTP headers to all the views, like this:

```
@auth.after_app_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
    response.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Expires'] = '0'
    return response
```

Although the latter seems like a bad idea.

P.S. Excuse my noobishness.

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question directly, but perhaps can solve your problem at all.
Working with Bootstrap should be simple, if you know the way to do it, otherwise, it can be quite confusing.

After dealing with this, I found a package named flask-bootstrap, which solved part of the problem. Then I wrote to myself (and made public) https://pypi.python.org/pypi/machete/, which is a tool to generate python code from templates.

In your case, you can try by entering an empty directory, and type:

```
$ machete -t bootstrap
```

The are other tools, like cookiecutter, but I didnt tried them yet.

This will create all the necessary files to make your code deployable on Pypi (if you want to), and will create all files with a runnable situation, just by typing:

```
$ python run.py
```

Then check the code. You can optionally do this just to understand how flask-bootstrap works (which is different from downloading bootstrap on bare hands, that looks like is your scenario). Or you can use this structure to code on.

This way, you can focus on coding, not solving installation problems.

Comment: Great advice! I'm aware of Flask-bootstrap extension, but still greedily decided to hand-code frontend part of the app while learning to code. Also, thank you for suggesting **machete** and **cookiecutter**. Those packages are new to me.